# Compare two lists element-wise and return the approximate value

Tags: python, list

I have two list as given below:

```
list1 = ['17_12_29', '17_08_04']

list2 = ['17_12_29_xyz','2017_12_29_abc', '17_08_04_mnp','17_08_04_mnp2',
         '2017_08_04_def', '17_08_05_pqr']
```

I want to compare the two list element wise and expecting the result as given below:-

```
res = ['17_12_29_xyz','2017_12_29_abc', '17_08_04_mnp','17_08_04_mnp2','2017_08_04_def'].
```

We have different library are available to get the result, but my constraint to use python code only.

Comment: What are the conditions for element to be in res.

Answer (score 2):

Using list comprehension and any

```
res = [x for x in list2 if any(y in x for y in list1)]

print(res) # Output: ['17_12_29_xyz', '2017_12_29_abc', '17_08_04_mnp', '17_08_04_mnp2', '2017_08_04_def']
```

Comment: @tapaskumar--Glad to help.  Any questions on the solution?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
res=[]
list1 = ['17_12_29', '17_08_04'] 
list2 = ['17_12_29_xyz','2017_12_29_abc', '17_08_04_mnp','17_08_04_mnp2', '2017_08_04_def', '17_08_05_pqr'] 
for item in list2:
    for j in list1:
        if j in item:
            res.append(item)
            break
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a string exists within another string in python.

```
res = []
for s2 in list2:
   for s1 in list1:
     if s1 in s2:
       res.append(s2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna use `in` for comparison:

```py
res=[]
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        if i in j:
            res.append(j)
```